# Angular 2 Hidden directive not updating on input field change

Tags: angular

I've got 2 child components. One child has an input field. If the input field is empty, the other child should be hidden. Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XiLrzQ6BVd0kFLjHftAP).

When adding `(keyup.enter)` to clear the value in the input field, the component that should be hidden stays unhidden.

In the plunker, try typing in a word in the input field. Then erase it. The hidden component works.

Now try typing in a word, and then press `enter`. The input field is empty, but the hidden component stays unhidden.

What am I doing wrong? The hidden directives conditional is based on the input field value, but I guess the change in the input field doesn't update the dom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason** : *You don't emit data when enter is pressed !*

[Your working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gAMFRmBVFRdSS0W6P90x?p=preview)

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="0" #input (keyup.enter)="itemInput.emit('')" [(ngModel)]="input.value" (ngModelChange)="itemInput.emit(input)">
```

Comment: I'm curious why you need the ngModelChange when you have 2-way data binding on the ngModel?

Comment: ngModelChange can be used when you want to do something eg. call a function when model's value is changed. @Jarvis here i'm emitting data when model's value gets changed.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I'm currently having trouble with setting values using 3rd party stuff in a form, but my model isn't getting updated so I'm digging around trying to figure it out. Took me a bit to just figure out how to get my custom component to work properly with forms... :-P

Comment: @Jarvis Cheers ! Happy coding with Angular2.